# Mesh with full weight moves less than bone, and moves another mesh with no weight

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

So The object on the left has a full weight and it moves slower than the bone when they are both moved. The second mesh has a weight of 0 for the bone on the left and does not move like it's supposed to. The mesh on the right has a full weight for its bone (right bone) and does not move when its bone is moved, yet the mesh on the left does while having a weight of 0.

I tried removing the armature modifier on both meshes (as you can see, one still does not have the modifier) and re-applying them, but the same issue is occurring. I even deleted the bones, created new ones, re-positioned them and still a fail.

What problem is occurring and how do I fix it?[image]

Also, there are two spheres that contain these objects and they move the same speed as the bones do when moved, and don't move the one on the other side.

EDIT: Here is the .blend file.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In edit mode, if you select a vertex you can read - in the "N" panel - all the weighted bones, so to understand why the vertex is moving that way: if you want the vertex to move exactly with a bone it should be weighted to that bone only (even if the weight is not full 1.0).
If this does not resolve the problem I think you should upload the file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that changed much, for when one vertex was set to have a value of 1, it didn't move more than the others. I'll upload the file.